# Not able to view kafka consumer output while executing in ECLIPSE: PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I installed kafka and zookeeper in windows system. i have started kafka and zookeeper servers, created topic "javainuse-topic" , started producer and consumer with the below commands

> .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
>
> .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
>
> .\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181
> --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic javainuse-topic
>
> .\bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092
> --topic javainuse-topic
>
> .\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server
> localhost:9092 --topic javainuse-topic --from-beginning

i am able to transfer data successfully from producer to consumer. So, i have wrote below code in eclipse and tried to execute it in local. but i am not able to view the consumer data in my eclipse console.

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.3.0 pyspark-shell'

import sys
import time
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils


n_secs = 1
topic = "javainuse-topic"

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaStreamProcessor").setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, n_secs)
    
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {
                        'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092', 
                        'group.id':'javainuse-topic', 
                        'fetch.message.max.bytes':'15728640',
                        'auto.offset.reset':'largest'})
                        # Group ID is completely arbitrary

lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
counts.pprint()

ssc.start()
time.sleep(6) # Run stream for 10 minutes just in case no detection of producer
# ssc.awaitTermination()
ssc.stop(stopSparkContext=True,stopGraceFully=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try again but this time setting `auto.offset.reset` to `'earliest'` (or `'smallest'` if you are using the old consumer).

```
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {
                        'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092', 
                        'group.id':'javainuse-topic', 
                        'fetch.message.max.bytes':'15728640',
                        'auto.offset.reset':'earliest'})
                        # Group ID is completely arbitrary
```

Comment: when i use "earliest" error i got : Wrong value earliest of auto.offset.reset in ConsumerConfig; Valid values are smallest and largest

Comment: Use smallest then. I mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: Code worked fine when i use smallest. but after few secounds i got below error
"Failed to delete: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-e507ff54-adcf-43c4-92c4-77a8f913b29a\userFiles-ef0538e2-7da1-491c-8586-f0ca76cd3cb4"

Comment: Can you please ask a new question so that you can post the full error?

Comment: And it his answer has solved your question regarding auto.offset.reset please mark it as accepted.

Comment: spark is not executing continuously, spark is getting closed when it executes ones.Since it is a streaming process it has to detect data for evry 1 secound as per my code right?

Comment: @LUZO uncomment `ssc.awaitTermination()` if you want it to continuously run